# difference between apostrophe and single quote in rails

Tags: javascript, jsx

I have a problem that when I use actual single quotation mark instead of apostrophe which is provided in keyboard, actual single quotation is not presented on view

for example I have `jsx` file as below.

```
showText() {
    let { name } = this.props.person;
      case "Personal" :
        return `who have seen ‘${name}’`;
      default:
        return "etc";
    }
  }
```

Here I used `‘’` instead of `''`. I thought using single quote is more accurate than apostrophe, but is there any difference between using single quote?

Comment: ` is a backtick, and is something that can be used to define multiline string literals. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.  A single quote ' is an apostrophe.

Comment: Not JS fan, but the apostrophe can't be used to create strings, being inside a template literal is just part of the string. Editting to change tags.